# How to perform a relaxation of an integer linear programming formulation of graph vertex cover?

Tags: algorithm, graph, linear-programming, vertex-cover

I'm implementing the optimization algorithms from [Kernelization Algorithms for the Vertex Cover Problem: Theory and Experiments (PDF)](http://www.siam.org/meetings/alenex04/abstacts/F-Abu-Khzam.pdf).

I'm a bit stuck at chapter 2.3: *Kernelization by linear programming*.

The idea of this technique (in ILP formulation) is to assign a weight `X_u \in \left\{ 0,1 \right\}` to each vertex `u` (also denoted as `v`) of the input graph `G=\left\( V,E \right\)` to satisfy the following constraints:

- Minimize the sum of weights `\Sigma_uX_u`
- Satisfy `X_u + X_v  \geq 1` whenever `\left\{ u,v \right \}` are connected by an edge in the graph.

So, as output I get a set of vertices having `X_v` of 1 and the rest, having `X_v` of 0.
The paper says that the relaxation is based on replacing `X_u \in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}` by `X_u \geq 0`. ([S. Khuller (PDF)](http://www.tcs.fudan.edu.cn/rudolf/Courses/Algorithms/Alg_cs_08w/Resources/khuller_vc02.pdf) points out that in this case `X_u \in \left \{ 0,0.5,1 \right \}`). That relaxation would lead to having 3 groups of vertices with weights of 1, 0.5 and 0.

My problem is that I am not quite sure how to approach the weight assignment.

From what I was able to understand, to minimize the sum of weights it would be best to (for each edge) focus on the vertices with the highest degrees first, and when their weight is already greater than zero, add the value to vertex on the second end of analyzed edge.

This leads me (correctly?) to the situation where actually `X_v \in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}` for each vertex in the basic formulation. When I'm thinking of relaxing the integer constraint, that just changes to `X_v \in \left \{ 0,0.5 \right \}`.

What's the flaw in my logic?

How would I need to approach the relaxation to have vertices with weight 1 and 0 as well as 0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, the constraint `X_v in {0, 1/2, 1}` is not amenable to formulation as a (fractional) linear program. What's going on here is that, if you set the weaker constraint `X_v >= 0`, then there exists some optimal solution where `X_v in {0, 1/2, 1}` holds for all `v`, though in general not every optimal solution has this property. Section 6 of the paper that you linked presents an algorithm that finds such an optimal solution for the vertex cover LP.

Comment: So, to put it into 'human' terms, I'm not able to easily discern a straightforward rule for ILP->LP relaxation in this context i.e. it exists rather only in the theoretical space?


It makes me wonder, because as You may see in the summary of the first paper, it is stated that kernelization by linear programming has been practically applied to achieve results presented there. Am I missing a piece of the puzzle here?

Comment: @helluin The (fractional) LP formulation is derived mechanically from the ILP formulation by replacing constraints like x in {0, 1} with 0 <= x <= 1 (the x <= 1 part is redundant for the vertex cover LP because there's no reason to make x larger). Vertex cover is NP-hard, so we can't solve the ILP directly. Linear programming is tractable (I'm being vague because the situation is complicated), so we can solve the (fractional) LP. Generic LP solvers may have x equal to any value in the interval [0, 1]. The specialized solver in Section 6 has all x values in {0, 1/2, 1}.

Comment: @helluin That solver works by solving vertex cover on a *bipartite* (that's important, because it makes the problem tractable) graph derived by sort of "cross-stitching" two copies of the input graph, then averaging the two solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made it very clear. Is it just me or is what You've just said not stated in any way in the chapter related to LP formulation?

Comment: @helluin I honestly didn't read the paper carefully enough to know. The material about deriving LP relaxations often is assumed to be background knowledge by researchers writing for expert audiences. I read about a paragraph of Section 6 to remind myself how the algorithm goes.